# Getting PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed.while invoking web service

Tags: java, web-services

I am having https service url. I wrote java client using SAAJ. but i am getting the below exception:--

java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

> > I exported the certificate from service URL (using browser.) and saved as jssecacerts 
> >     Then imporetd this by using the following command--> keytool -import -file jssecacerts -keystore cacerts

Now I wrote the java client using SAAJ as below:-

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/Program  Files/Java/jre6/lib/security/cacerts"); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit"); 
URL url = new URL("https://whatever.com/service"); 
SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance(); 
connection = scf.createConnection(); 
response = connection.call(message, url);
```

I dont know where I am wrong...Please help...me....I am in seriously in trouble.. 
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: were u able to find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to set those system properties.  if you successfully imported the certs into the jre's cacerts file, then they should be good to go.  i'm assuming you are using the "java" from "C:/Program  Files/Java/jre6/bin/java.exe" to actually run your program.

btw, why are you getting a PrivilegedActionException?  that implies that you are running with some sort of SecurityManager or within a PrivilegedAction call?

Comment: Just for future Questions/Answers. If you had the time and post a new Question, ask for help and expect an answer, then please - provide the solution when the problem is fixed/solved, not just "I fixed it byby tnx".